# Android Studio, Fire TV - Issues compiling with Amazon SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, amazon-fire-tv

I'm still exceptionally new to Android Development, about 2 weeks in to my first project. So, a resolution may be obvious, and I can only hope this eventually helps another in my shoes.

The goal was to build an app for FireTV that would stream media (on-demand or live video stream).

I started research on Amazon's developer portal, downloaded AS, Amazon SDK, and anything else I was told I would need to continue. My first thoughts were to familiarize myself with Lollipop, using Google TV's for emulator, and using the TV Activity template, which from what I see is heavily based on the Leanback library.  I built and tested and modified to my hearts content, and had a working app, using emulators that can handle api21. Then came the time to 'retro-fit' what I had working with Amazon's Fire TV sdk Add-On (API 17). Learned a bit about AppCompat and a few other errors along the way, most I could figure out on my own. But now, I'm stuck.

Gradle won't compile now that I'm using the FireTV add-on, and the console output isn't helpful to me, at this level.

*"* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\path\to\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\path\to\sdk\platforms\android-17\android.jar -M C:\path\to\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -I C:\path\to\sdk\add-ons\addon-amazon_fire_tv_addon-amazon-17\libs\notification.jar -I C:\path\to\sdk\add-ons\addon-amazon_fire_tv_addon-amazon-17\libs\gamecontroller.jar -S C:\path\to\app\build\intermediates\res\debug -A C:\path\to\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug -m -J C:\path\to\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\path\to\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.d53e.rbeal.fntsysportsnetwork -0 apk --output-text-symbols C:\path\to\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug
>   Error Code:
>       1
>   Output:
>       ERROR: Asset package include 'C:\path\to\sdk\add-ons\addon-amazon_fire_tv_addon-amazon-17\libs\notification.jar' not found.
>   * Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.*
>   "

Been stuck here for two days, running short on time and am urgently needing progress.  Can't figure out how to include --stacktrace or --info as suggested.

In panic, i tried to port the project to eclipse, and as an end result am stuck with "Cannot Resolve 'R'" errors, the only fix I can find is to change the build target, but I think I need to use Amazon's.

I'd rather use Android Studio, but at this point any help would be greatly appreciated.

build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
//    compileSdkVersion 21
    compileSdkVersion "Amazon.com:Amazon Fire TV SDK Addon:17"
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.d53e.myname.appname"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.amazon.device.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
}
```

(project) build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.amazon.device.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of those moments where i want to slam my head against a wall...

Manually copy the file into the "projectName/app/libs" folder, 
Change the project explorer view to project, so you can see the libs folder
Right click on the item[s] within, and select "Add as Library"

Much like that last step in eclipse.

Comment: Well I got the same problem... Have already tried to manually add the two libraries but Android Studio / Gradle tells me: Asset package include 'D:\SDK\....\notification.jar' not found. Any idea?

Comment: Which file you have mentioned to copy into "projectName/app/libs" ? I am also facing this issue.